# Combine two lists by each element

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I am new to python and want to combine/merge two lists by element like this:

**Input**

```
list = ['blue', 'red', 'green'] 
list2= ['trousers', 'shirt', 'pants']
```

**Desired Output**

```
desired list= ['blue trousers', 'blue shirt', 'blue pants', 'red trouser', 'red shirt', 'red pants',         'green trouser', 'green shirt', 'green pants']
```

I have researched stackoverflow and there came up the itertools library and the cartesian product.
So I tried this:

```
from itertools import product 
  
def cartesian_product(arr1, arr2): 
  
    # return the list of all the computed tuple 
    # using the product() method 
    return list(product(arr1, arr2))  
    
# Driver Function  
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    arr1 = ['blue', 'red', 'green'] 
    arr2 = ['trouser', 'shirt', 'pants'] 
    print(cartesian_product(arr1, arr2))
```

This is the output which comes close (but packing the results into tuples instead of elements):

```
[('blue', 'trouser'), ('blue', 'shirt'), ('blue', 'pants'), ('red', 'trouser'), ('red', 'shirt'), ('red', 'pants'), ('green', 'trouser'), ('green', 'shirt'), ('green', 'pants')]
```

Any suggestion how I get to the desired output from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using the following technique (no use of itertools):

```
list1 = ['blue', 'red', 'green'] 
list2 = ['trousers', 'shirt', 'pants']
desired_list = []

for colour in list1:
    for garment in list2:
        desired_list.append(colour + ' ' + garment)
```

For each element in the first list, this iterates through each element in the second list, giving the following output:

```
['blue trousers', 'blue shirt', 'blue pants', 'red trousers', 'red shirt',
'red pants', 'green trousers', 'green shirt', 'green pants']
```

Apologies if there is a more efficient way of doing this! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that is a straight forward solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [('blue', 'trouser'), ('blue', 'shirt'), ('blue', 'pants'), ('red', 'trouser'), ('red', 'shirt'), ('red', 'pants'), ('green', 'trouser'), ('green', 'shirt'), ('green', 'pants')]
for i in x:
     y += [i[0] + " " + i[1]]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
['blue trouser', 'blue shirt', 'blue pants', 'red trouser', 'red shirt', 'red pants', 'green trouser', 'green shirt', 'green pants']
```